# Autocomplete function names in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a short question for Xcode users , is it possible to autocomplete functions like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("%s \n", "A string"); //<--
    return 0;
}
```

I mean like in Visual Studio where you start to type the function name prin... and it gives you some similar function names back.
After pressing enter it will write the full function name down and show you what arguments you have to provide if the target function takes any arguments. Can anybody point me to a source or give me a an answer to this ?

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Comment: @molbdnilo and how long is the long answer ?

Comment: If you want a longer answer you're going to need to ask a longer question.

Comment: @molbdnilo please point me to any useful source on how to achieve this autocomplete function